# ColorAnimation starts only if a color is set

Tags: wpf

On the startup window, a grid with a TextBlock is defined, like follows:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="stackoverflow.com"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Foreground="Yellow">
        <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="200"
                                         Duration="0:0:5"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.FontSize)" />

                        <ColorAnimation To="Blue"
                                        Duration="0:0:5"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBlock.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Within the TextBlock, a simple DoubleAnimation and a ColorAnimation is defined, so nothing spectacular. After pressing F5 in VS, the animation starts directly.

A strange behavior appears after removing `Foreground="Yellow"`. By default, the Foreground of a TextBlock is set to black (depending on the preferred system theme). Now both animations should start and the colors should go from black to blue. That isn’t so, the animation won’t start. Also by setting in the ColorAnimation the `From` property to black, the animation doesn’t start.

Why does this behavior appear and what is the reason? From my point of view, I cannot see a logical reason whether its matter to set a color or not.

### Edit (additional information)

An exception won’t thrown whether the Foreground property is set or not. The funny thing is now that if the Foreground property is not set, the default color will be chosen. You can simply verify it by writing following: `Debug.WriteLine(this.textBlock.Foreground.ToString());` (Name of the TextBlock additionally added). The color gets resolved by the system. Also by changing the Windows Theme, the color gets resolved. So, the color is implicitly set to the TextBlock. Should be work, right?

Writing `Foreground="Back"` doesn't match to the current selected Windows theme. Instead of doing this, I would prefer a DynamicResource as follows

```
Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"
```

The StaticResource works fine whereas the DynamicResource won’t work, so the animation doesn’t start.

First, WPF knows the implicit color. Second, the DynamicResource won’t for any reason work. Why? Possible bug?

Answer (score 1):

If the value is not set an exception is thrown, you cannot animate the default foreground because the instance is immutable. (If you trigger the animation using the loaded event like this it will just be swallowed.)

Comment: According to your response, I've edited my question. Could you dig deeper regarding the immutable types in WPF?

Comment: @System.Data: Most of those workings are internal to the dp-system so i cannot tell you anything with certainty. I only got my test application to throw the exception which states that the problem is immutability of the target. Using StaticResource is like directly setting a value on the object, so that works, DynamicResource however creates a reference. The animation code actually has some mechanism to copy freezables, but this apparently does not help here.